# Nextjs trying to access local storage before initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to achieve next: I have sidebar with 2 buttons, contact and profile. whenever user clicks either of them the URL updates to: `/?section=clickedItem` so user can save state and on refresh can return to that page. to control the state i'm using this code:

checking either query or localstorage to see which component to load

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (router.isReady) {
      const sectionFromURL = router.query.section;
      const sectionFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('section');
      const chatFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('chat');
      setCurrentSection(sectionFromURL || sectionFromStorage || 'contacts');
      setSelectedChat(chatFromStorage || null);
    }
  }, [router.isReady]);
```

Update state in local storage whenever it changes

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(currentSection);
    if (router.isReady) {
      localStorage.setItem('section', currentSection);
      router.push({
        pathname: router.pathname,
        query: { section: currentSection },
      });
    }

    if (selectedChat) {
      localStorage.setItem('chat', selectedChat);
    }
  }, [currentSection, selectedChat]);
```

the **problem** is next :  whenever i visit localhost:3000/?section=contacts , it works fine and loads the selected element. same with profile. however, loading localhost:3000 always defaults to contacts , changes url to that and also writes contacts in the localstorage

problem seems to be this section

```
const sectionFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('section');
setCurrentSection(sectionFromURL || sectionFromStorage || 'contacts');
```

currectSection always gets set to 'contacts'

Comment: Are you running the second useEffect method in the same file ?

Comment: @NicholasMberev yep, both are in the same file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct behavior of what you declared in `useEffect`.

On each first render, all `useEffect`s run.

The first one is checking whether you have a value in url or localStorage and if not you're setting its value to `"contacts"`

The second one possibly starts with `currentSection` as `undefined` and it is setting the localStorage value to that, then receives a change of the first one which set `currentSection` to `"contacts"`, runs for a second time and writes it into the storage.

If you want to prevent this from happening, in the second `useEffect` check whether value of `currentSection` is `undefined`, and if not run the effect you want. This will prevent setting `"contacts"` as the default value.

Comment: GOD BLESS YOU,  finally it got fixed